# Validate added fields on user registration - Joomla 1.7

Tags: php, validation, registration, joomla1.7

I've added some fields and plugins to my Joomla 1.7 user registration form.

I'd like to add some ajax validation when the user puts its mail for eg.
then a message apears saying that the mail is already registered.

Maybe it's someting like puting some property in the XML file of fields indicating wich JS validation should run.

Could someone explain how it works please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way that i've used was by creating a plugin and validating on the "before register" event and trigger an error if the validation failed.
the ajax way seemed to be a little more complicated.